# vendor_prefix selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to execute [cdp commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) using asyncio and like the [execute_cdp_cmd](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) command in selenium and i also found the undocumented (maybe i dont have the correct documentation) endpoint url of the chrome webdriver, see here [executeCdpCommand](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/64447d4b03f6986337d1ca8d8b6476653570bcc1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromium/remote_connection.py).

```
self._commands['executeCdpCommand'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/{}/cdp/execute'.format(vendor_prefix))
```

As you can see I need a vendor_prefix to correctly execute the cdp command.
The only sentence I found was in the source's docstring of the  [ChromiumDriver in selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/fc05f3a89ef5960448f909627118541868513563/py/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py).

```
 - vendor_prefix - Company prefix to apply to vendor-specific WebDriver extension commands.
```

I couldn't find the anything useful on the internet, does anybody know the answer and could give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the [java source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/e6366da0161af746ab1d449838ba280b6cfd7854/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/AddHasCdp.java) for selenium the google chrome vendor prefix which is expect by the webdriver it is:

```
  @Override
  public Map<String, CommandInfo> getAdditionalCommands() {
    return ImmutableMap.of(
      EXECUTE_CDP, new CommandInfo("session/:sessionId/goog/cdp/execute", HttpMethod.POST));
  }
```